# How to use 'git diff -G' to exclude certain patterns

Tags: git, git-diff

I would like to ignore certain changes when using Git diff (version bumps).  I saw there is a `-G` flag; however, I don't seem to have any luck with it.  I also saw a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word), but that doesn't seem to help.

I am hoping to do something like this:

`git diff <hash> --unified=0 -G "^.*\<version\>.*"`

I would expect this to include anything with <version> in it; however, that doesn't happen.  It seems to not make any difference.  I'd like to invert it if possible, but I think getting a basic regex is step 1.